# I'd like a rigorous proof that the dihedral group $D_8$ is the isometry group of the unit square

Tags: geometry

My geometry is woefully inadequate.  Can someone help me show that
$D_8 = \langle r, s \mid r^4 = s^2 = 1, rs = sr^{-1} \rangle$ is exactly the group of isometries of $S = [0,1]\times[0,1]$?  Of course, showing that $r =$ rotation 90 degrees and $s =$ reflection are isometries is not hard, but how do I know they are the *only* ones?

Here's what I have so far.

Say $\phi : S \rightarrow S$ is an isometry.  First of all corners must map to corners, since they are the unique points $p$ such that there exists $q$ with $d(p,q) = \sqrt{2}$.  Then adjacent corners must map to adjacent corners.  But how do I know that some "twisting" doesn't happen within the square (e.g. like what can happen with a conformal map)?

Comment: That's not quite enough, because there could conceivably be isometries of the square that don't extend to the entire plane.

Answer (score 1):

You can uniquely identify any point of $[0,1] \times [0, 1]$ -- or indeed any point of the plane whatsoever -- by specifying its distances from any three of the corners of the square.  Consequently, once you've decided where an isometry takes the corners, the rest of the isometry is determined.

Comment: This makes sense for the edges, but what about the points in the interior of the square?

Comment: Oh, I thought you were talking about the square, not about $[0, 1] \times [0, 1]$.

Comment: @DA1729 Note that the edit makes this a solution.  In fact, the points of $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ are determined by their distance to any two adjacent corners: the points of fixed distance from either form a circle, these two circles intersect at two points, and one of them is outside of the square.

Comment: @Slade That's exactly the key I was looking for.  Thanks.